# Test the convergence of the series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\log (k+1)-\log k}{\arctan (2/k)}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

Test the convergence of the series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\log (k+1)-\log k}{\arctan (2/k)}$.

How can I test the convergence of this series using comparison test? I'm out of ideas and I would greatly appreciate any suggestions or solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use *equivalents:*

- $\log(k+1)-\log k=\log\Bigl(1+\dfrac1k\Bigr)\sim_\infty\dfrac 1k$,
- $\arctan\dfrac2k\sim_\infty\dfrac 2k$,

hence it diverges trivially since the general term doesn't even tend to $0$:
$$\frac{\log(k+1)-\log k}{\arctan\dfrac2k}\sim_\infty\dfrac{\dfrac 1k}{\,\dfrac 2k\,}=\frac12$$